# How to solve Spring Jackson infinite recursion without losing serialization?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

The spring infinite recursion is a classical spring error that can be easily managed with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackedReference, however, logically, using these annotation can cause some problems:

1. Multiple @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackedReference annotations inside a class cause a problem where you need to specifically give a value name to each annotation to compose a Json couple otherwise you'll get a runtime server error, if you have many of them this process is uncomfortable
2. If you need to serialize these objects, this is a major problem. For example I had an entity that required serialization to be sent in kafka topic, but using these annotation made the serialization skip the proporties annotated with @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference (logically as stated in the Jackson documentation for these annotations)

Is there a way to solve this problem without having to lose serialization properties or write dirty code?

This is a quick example, this property won't be serialized and since it belongs to a class where many @JsonBackReference are needed you have to specify a value

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Restaurant.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
@JsonBackReference(value = "orders") //not so clean
private Restaurant restaurant;
```

Comment: Have you considered using `@JsonIdentityInfo` instead?